# Retrieve total count of paginated records along side custom limit in Cake PHP 2 paginator

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I'm working inside a legacy Cake PHP 2.10 application and am utilising both the [Pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination) component and [PaginationHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#paginatorhelper).

I've had to override the `paginateCount` method to set a custom option for my paginator settings to limit the maximum number of query results which are then paginated, `limit` and `maxLimit` are not sufficient on their own - I've added `totalLimit`.

The problem now is if there are less results than my `totalLimit`, such as when filtering, it continues to display **20,000** rather than the number of actual results. I could create another query specifically for this count, but wondered if there's a quick workaround that I'm missing, here's my my `Application` model method:

```php
public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array())
{
        if (isset($extra['totalLimit'])) {
                return $extra['totalLimit'];
        }
}
```

And my pagination set up:

```php
// define pagination settings
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'Application' => array(
                'paramType' => 'querystring',
                'totalLimit' => 20000,
                'limit' => $filters['pagination']['perPage'],
                'maxLimit' => $filters['pagination']['perPage'],
                'fields' => array(
                        'Application.*',
                        'ApplicationPayday.*',
                        'ApplicationApiLink.*',
                        'ApplicationResponse.*',
                        'AffiliateId.*',
                        'Redirect.*'
                ),
                'joins' => array(
                        array(
                                'table' => 'tlp_application_paydays',
                                'alias' => 'ApplicationPayday',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                        'ApplicationPayday.application_id = Application.id'
                                )
                        ),
                        array(
                                'table' => 'tlp_application_api_links',
                                'alias' => 'ApplicationApiLink',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                        'ApplicationApiLink.application_id = Application.id'
                                )
                        ),
                        array(
                                'table' => 'tlp_application_responses',
                                'alias' => 'ApplicationResponse',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                        'ApplicationResponse.application_id = Application.id'
                                )
                        ),
                        array(
                                'table' => 'tlp_affiliate_ids',
                                'alias' => 'AffiliateId',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                        'AffiliateId.aff_id = Application.tlp_aff_id'
                                )
                        ),
                        array(
                                'table' => 'tlp_redirects',
                                'alias' => 'Redirect',
                                'type' => 'LEFT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                        'Redirect.application_id = Application.id'
                                )
                        )
                ),
                'conditions' => $queryConditions,
                'group' => array(
                        'Application.id'
                ),
                'order' => array(
                        'Application.id' => 'desc'
                ),
                'recursive' => -1
        )
);

// run query to get applications via paginated settings
try {
        $applications = $this->Paginator->paginate('Application');
} catch (\NotFoundException $e) {
        $this->Session->setFlash("Page doesn't exist. We've reset your search filters and taken you to the first page.");
        return $this->redirect('/payday_admin/leads/');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you replace the number of total results that `paginateCounts` returns with `$extra['totalLimit']` that you set (20.000 in this case).

The `pagineCount()` function should be overridden with something like in the example below. This way you will insert your total limit in the `->find('count', [])` parameters and also keep the original count if your $extra['totalLimit'] parameter is not sent.

```
public function paginateCount($conditions, $recursive, $extra)
{
    if (isset($extra['totalLimit'])) {
        $limit = $extra['totalLimit'];
        unset($extra['totalLimit']);

        $count = $this->find('count', compact($conditions, $recursive, $limit, $extra));
        return (int)$count;
    }

    $count = $this->find('count', compact($conditions, $recursive, $extra));
    return (int)$count;
}
```

Your count will be limited to the maximum value of `totalLimit`, but will return the true count if it's lower.

If you have millions of rows with many joins I recommend caching the count. The cache key can be created by hashing the conditions and other parameters.

---

This is how the conditions are passed to the overridden `paginateCount()` from the model Class.

```
$this->Paginator->settings = [
    'limit' => 50,
    'contain' => [
        ...
    ],
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'joins' => $joins,
    'group' => $group
];

$this->Paginator->paginate('Model');
```

Comment: This is interesting, in practice though it's not limiting my query at all. I have millions of rows, and lots of joins. Before your answer I created a separate query, moved the contents of `$this->Paginator->settings` into there and did a `$this->Application->find('count', array())` and passed the output to the paginator. Why would your approach described be taking so long? I don't think it's limiting the query

Comment: If you have millions of rows with many joins it's normal to take some time. I am in a similar situation, and I limit the result by date. Last 3 months for example, and if the user needs a longer period of time he has to increase the date range. I also cache the count. The cache key is created by hashing the conditions and other parameters.

Comment: I think I see why it's so slow, in the `if` statment for the `totalLimit`, when I log the `$conditions` they're empty. This in affect means it would pull hundreds of millions of rows from my table, yet, if you refer to my original post, everything is listed in the paginator `Application`. How would I pass these conditions?

Comment: Looks like `compact()` is resetting my conditions, so logging `$conditions` and `$recursive` and `$extra` all independently gives me the correct values, but when using `compact()` I get an empty array, thus no query conditions applied which is resulting in the query count taking too long.

Comment: Hmm, you've got the idea, work to obtain a good array to be used in `find` `count`.

Comment: Use array_merge($conditions, $recursive, $extra, $limit) and $limit should be an array like  $limit = ['limit' =>$extra['totalLimit']]